Why is fully qualified syntax needed for default type arguments?
Consider the following valid Rust 1.79.0 code:
trait T {
    type A;
}

struct S<
    C: T,
    F: Fn(C::A) = fn(<C as T>::A)
>(C, F);

Replacing <C as T> with C yields
error[E0220]: associated type `A` not found for `C`

This feels redundant since it seems like the compiler should be able to infer this like in the trait bound Fn(C::A). Is this just not implemented yet, or is there a more fundamental reason?

A wild guess would be that this is a bug. I think you can report this.

Looks like it's already reported: #87682.

@eggyal This answers my question, thanks! Surprised that this issue has been open for 3 years now.
